# $2005$th derivative of $f$ at $0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, induction, recurrence-relations

So I tried using Leibnitz formula to solve by recurrence, but I can just get to one point and then it's a mess again. Problem is

> Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+2x+3x^2+\ldots+2005x^{2004}}$. Find $f^{[2005]}(0)$.

What I did is to notice that $f'=-f^2g$, where $g$ is the polynomial, and then tried to expand the result to higher order derivatives. By Leibnitz formula and the last expression, I got

$f^{[2005]}(0)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{2004}\binom{2004}{k}\left(f^2\right)^{[k]}(0)g^{[2004-k]}(0)=\sum_{k=0}^{2004}\binom{2004}{k}\left(f^2\right)^{[k]}(0)(2004-k)!
=\sum_{k=0}^{2004}\frac{2004!}{k!}\left(f^2\right)^{[k]}(0)$

I'd really appreciate some help here, please.

Comment: It should be useful that $$1+2x+3x^2+\cdots+2005x^{2004}=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}[1+x+x^2+x^3+ ...+x^{2005}] = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[\frac{x^{2006}-1}{x-1}\right]$$ but I don't yet see how.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence#Series.2C_sum_to_n_terms

Comment: Hint: multiply both numerator and denominator by $(1-x)^2$.

Comment: Simplify the denominator using the hints above  and then the series should give you $2006!$

Comment: You guys rock. Didn't even thought of watching the higher powers as $O(x^k)$. Thank you all, very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice 
$$\frac{1}{f(x)} =\sum_{k=0}^{2004} (k+1)x^k
= \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} - \sum_{k=2005}^{\infty}\right) (k+1)x^k
= \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} - 2006 x^{2005} + O(x^{2006})
$$
We have
$$f(x) 
= \frac{(1-x)^2}{1 - 2006 x^{2005} + O(x^{2006})}
= (1-x)^2\left( 1 + 2006 x^{2005} + O(x^{2006})\right)\\
= (1-x)^2 + 2006 x^{2005} + O(x^{2006})
$$
This implies $$f^{[2005]}(0) = 2006 \times 2005! = 2006!$$